# Compare coordinates of two images of different size

Tags: python, image, size, rescale

I'm working with python and I need to compute an intersection over union taking   into account a ground-truth and an anchor box (more in general two rectangles). The problem is that I generate my anchors on an image of size 53x64 while I have the coordinates of the ground-truth respect to an image of size 424x512. 
The information I have is:

- Anchors: [x1,y1, x2,y2] respect to 53x64 image;
- GT: [x1,y1,x2,y2] respect to 424x512 image;

In particular they are the coordinates of two opposite angles of a rectangle.
So the problem is that the distances and the areas in this way are not proportionate. 
So the question is, How I can compare in the right way this two element?

Comment: Would it help to know the second rectangle is exactly 8 times larger in both height and width, and is proportional?

Comment: It isn't so helpfull because the most important think that I need Is to have a match between cooridnates. In my problem is important the position

Comment: Well, if the resolutions are always the same it'd be sorta easy.  I'll take a crack at writing an answer. So if I understand correctly, you need to calculate what the values of x1, x2, y1, and y2 are in the second image by knowing what they are in the first image?

Comment: Yes. I want to transform the coordinates of the rectangle from the domain 53 x 64 to the domain 424 x 512

Comment: multiplying anchor coordinates by 8 gives you its position in larger image. but for intersection, the sizes would be the same? if at the moment the size is 1/64, then a better process would be to use an interpolation technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer. I hope I understood what you wanted correctly.

```py
Coordinates = {"x1" : 3, "x2" : 11, "y1" : 7, "y2" : 13}
NewCoords = {}
for key, value in Coordinates:
    NewCoords[key] = (value*8)
print(NewCoords)
# {"x1" : 24, "x2" : 88, "y1" : 56, "y2" : 104}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the information you have, you can transform the points given in anchor image coordinates to the equivalent on the ground-truth image. This can be done by using [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) as shown below. Similar math could be used to calculate an inverse (ground-truth ⇒ anchor) transformation.

You can use this to transform the coordinates you to their equivalent position relative to the ground-truth image. You should then be able to use these transformed values to calculate things like distances, angles, etc. properly.

````
anchor_height, anchor_width = 53, 64
gt_height, gt_width = 424, 512

def transform(x, y):
    return x/anchor_width * gt_width, y/anchor_height * gt_height

print(transform(0, 0))      # - > (0.0, 0.0)
print(transform(32, 26.5))  # - > (256.0, 212.0)
print(transform(64, 53))    # - > (512.0, 424.0)```
````